# Clear Google Drive Folder

Tags: directory, drive

Good afternoon,

I need help with cleaning a folder from my Corporate Google Drive.

I have this script below that cleans the folder when run by me, but it doesn't happen when another corporate user runs the same!
Receives Access Denied Error: Drive App

```
var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById("id folder")
var files = folder.getFiles()
while (files.hasNext()) {
files.next().setTrashed(true)
```

I appreciate if you can help me, I'm new to scripts

Comment: The folder id needs to be one that the user has permissions/access to.  If the user does not update the script with an id of a folder s/he has permissions/access to, the error can happen.  Have you asked the user if they have updated the folder Id? - Also, some folders might not be his/her so s/he will not be able to 'delete' them - script could check for access to delete permission before sending it to the trash

Comment: I provide the id of the folder and other users are allowed to access this folder! So I don't understand why this is!

Comment: Other users have (read, write) access to it but can they delete?

Comment: That's what I don't understand! I believe they could, because manually accessing the folder yes they can delete! More via script this is not happening and I don't know what to do if something is missing in my script!

Comment: I already mentioned that your script is missing the check for access for each item before sending it to the trash.  I.e. the items inside the folder

Comment: I don't know how to solve this, as I said I'm a newbie, if you can help me I'm very grateful!